# How do I get a substring of a string in Julia?

Tags: string, julia

Is there a way in Julia that gets from one particular character to another? For example, I want to get the variable `s="Hello, world"` of 3 to 9 characters.

```
# output = 'llo, wo'
```

Comment: In Julia your output will be `"llo, wo"` as the single quote is reserved for `Char` only.

Answer (score 12):

The other solution is working for ASCII only strings. However, Julia uses *byte indexing* not *character indexing* in `getindex` syntax, as I have discussed on [my blog](https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2020/08/13/strings.html) some time ago. If you want to use character indexing (which I assume you do from the wording of your question) [here](https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2020/08/29/charindex.html) you have a solution using macros.

In general (without using the solution linked above) the functions to use are: `chop`, `first`, `last`, or for index manipulation `prevind`, `nextind`, and `length`.

So e.g. to get characters from 3 to 9 a safe syntaxes are e.g. (just showing several combinations)

```
julia> str = " Hello! "
" Hello! "

julia> last(first(str, 9), 7)
"Hello! "

julia> chop(str, head=2, tail=length(str)-9)
"Hello! "

julia> chop(first(str, 9), head=2, tail=0)
"Hello! "

julia> str[(:)(nextind.(str, 0, (3, 9))...)]
"Hello! "
```

Note though that the following is incorrect:

```
julia> str[3:9]
ERROR: StringIndexError: invalid index [3], valid nearby indices [1]=>'', [5]=>' '
```

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/37397) to make `chop` more flexible which would simplify your specific indexing case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method:

```
s="Hello, world"

s[3:9]
# output: llo, wo

s[3:end]
# output: llo, world
```

Comment: This is not a general solution: `"Milchmädchen"[8:end]` gives a `StringIndexError` as noted in the other answer. Unfortunately, `SubString` is also no solution for the given range.

Answer (score 0):

As was noted by Bogumił Kamiński, Julia uses *byte indexing*, which kind of gets in the way when one wants to have something similar to the behavior I get in Wolfram Mathematica:

```
StringTake["Milchmädchen", {8, 12}]
(* "dchen" *)
```

Coming from a high-level language like the Wolfram Language, the behavior in Julia—even for a higher level function like `SubString` is confusing:

```
julia> SubString("Milchmädchen", 9, 13)
"dchen"
    
julia> length("Milchmädchen")
12
```

So, an immediately reasonable approach might be to work with a *collection* of characters and *concatenate* the result of any extractions:

```
"Works like SubString, but is character indexed"
function stringtake(s::AbstractString, i::Integer, j::Integer=length(s))
    characters = collect(s)
    ind_i, ind_j = max(1, i), min(j, length(s))
    return join(characters[ind_i:ind_j])
end
```

While this is straight forward, it may be expensive for large strings as we needed to create an array of *all characters*. Prof. Kaminski has shown other approaches, e.g., using *indexing functions*. As of `v1.9` (thanks @DNF for pointing this out), we may use the [`graphemes`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Unicode/#Unicode.graphemes) function from the `Unicode` module in the Julia Standard Library, which will iterate over [*graphemes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) in any string:

```
import Unicode

"Works like SubString, but is character indexed"
function stringtake(s::AbstractString, i::Integer, j::Integer=length(s))
    ind_i, ind_j = max(i, 1), min(j, length(s))
    return Unicode.graphemes(s, ind_i:ind_j)
end
```

With one of these implementations in place we can do the following in a REPL:

```
julia> stringtake("Milchmädchen", 8, 12)
"dchen"

julia> stringtake("Hello, world", 3, 9)
"llo, wo"

julia> stringtake(" Hello! ", 3)
"Hello! "
```

Comment: In newer versions of Julia you can use `graphemes` from the Unicode stdlib for this. And, BTW, in you `stringtake` function, there is a typo: the last input argument should be `j`.